# Initializing new node

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

When you initialize a new node for linked list, such as `Node front = new Node()` and say set this data to point to the current data in the current node like:

```
front.setData(current.getData());
```

Does the initialization of the new Node appear at the beginning or the front of the linked list?

Comment: Show us Node. I assume it has a pointer to the previous entry and that would determine where it is.

Comment: This is a very confusing question, I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.  As it stands, the code snippet here is very implementation-specific and doesn't make much sense without the rest of the code.  Also not sure what you mean by "at the beginning or the front".

Answer (score 1):

you must give link as a beginning node.. like this

```
front.setData(current.getData());
front.prev = null;
front.next = head.next;
head = front;
```

Comment: That is not a standard linked list, that would be a doubly linked list